How to Create Groups in Firebase Cloud Messaging HTTP V1 API?
I am currently migrating from the Firebase Legacy API to the HTTP V1 API for Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM). While the HTTP V1 documentation provides details on sending messages to groups, I couldn't find any information on how to create or manage groups using the HTTP V1 API.
In the Legacy API, we used to create notification groups using endpoints like /notification and manage device registration tokens within those groups. However, it seems like the process has changed in the HTTP V1 API, and I'm not sure how to proceed with creating and managing these groups.
I went through the official Firebase Cloud Messaging HTTP V1 API documentation but couldn't find relevant details about creating groups.
I searched for related discussions and posts but couldn't find a clear solution.
Any guidance or examples on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated!
How can I create a notification group in Firebase Cloud Messaging using the HTTP V1 API?
What is the recommended way to add or remove device tokens from a notification group in the new API?
Are there any official Firebase guidelines or best practices for managing groups of devices using the HTTP V1 API?

Here's the detailed documentation regarding creating and managing groups.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/device-group
FYI :- You can store only upto 20 users in single group. And if you have huge number of device token then you have to use topic.
